# Type safety with map, slice or channel types

Tags: go, type-safety

I wonder why this code compiles in go. I expected a compiler error as I would with e.g. string:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type myMap map[string]int
type mySlice []int
type myChan chan int

type myString string

func main() {
    var mm myMap
    var m map[string]int
    m = mm // fine, but expected compiler error

    var ms mySlice
    var s []int
    s = ms // same with slices

    var mc myChan
    var c chan int
    c = mc // or channels

    var mstr myString
    var str string
//  str = mstr // error, as expected
    fmt.Printf("%T %T %T %T %T %T %T %T\n", mm, m, ms, s, mc, c, mstr, str)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/y4-xqNabAk8)
Why don't I get a type mismatch error with those special "reference types" map, slice and chan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get no compile-time error in the first 2 cases because those *assignments* are allowed by the language spec.

[Spec: Assignments:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments)

> In assignments, each value must be [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to the type of the operand to which it is assigned...

And [Spec: Assignability:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability)

> A value `x` is *assignable* to a [variable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) of type `T` ("`x` is assignable to `T`") if one of the following conditions applies:
>
> - `x`'s type is identical to `T`.
> - **`x`'s type `V` and `T` have identical [underlying types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) and at least one of `V` or `T` is not a [defined](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions) type.**
> - `T` is an interface type and `x` [implements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) `T`.
> - `x` is a bidirectional channel value, `T` is a channel type, `x`'s type `V` and `T` have identical element types, and at least one of `V` or `T` is not a defined type.
> - `x` is the predeclared identifier `nil` and `T` is a pointer, function, slice, map, channel, or interface type.
> - `x` is an untyped [constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) [representable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Representability) by a value of type `T`.

The emphasized rule applies to your first 2 cases. It however does not apply to your last case, because both `string` and `myString` are defined types. None of the rules apply in your last case.

Answer (score 1):

According to the language spec:

> x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a defined type.

`myMap` is a defined type, but `map[string]int` is not, and since the underlying types are identical, assignment works.

`string` is a defined type, so assignment to another defined type does not work. You have to explicitly copy.